# How to link fancy radio buttons to same ID?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to use these [funky radio buttons](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/funky-radio-buttons) though the radio buttons have an id=radio1, id=radio2, id=radio3 etc

I would like all of them to have id-radio1 so it writes the result to radio1 in the database:

Here is how I have normal radio buttons working in the past using the same id and they toggle between one another:

```
      <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <label class="control-label form-check-inline">Gender</label>*
          <div class="form-group">       
                    <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="Gender" value="M" required="required" /><label class="control-label">Male</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="Gender" value="F" required="required" /><label class="control-label">Female</label>
          </div>  
      </div>
```

$Gender=$_POST["Gender"];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[SubmissionsTBL]
[Gender]
VALUES
(,'".trimText($Gender)."')

Though, with the funky radio buttons chaning from this:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
        <label for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2"/>
        <label for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

to this doesn't work - it doesn't allow me to toggle radio buttons:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1" />
        <label for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio1"/>
        <label for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>

</div>
```

What is stopping the toggle?
Thank you!

Comment: I think you are mistaking id for name.  use name="radio1" but keep the ids unique.

Comment: Thank you. So how do I link a group of radio buttons to the same form result then?

Comment: In `$_POST["Gender"]`, "Gender" is actually the `name` not `id`.

Comment: lamelemon and andi thank you - that is the core of my problem here. User error haha. Thank you. All makes sense now.

Comment: oh - one more thing.  the label's `for` attribute has to match the `id` of the element it is labeling.  So when you said it didn't toggle, you were probably clicking on the word Female and not the little radio button circle, and since you had a mismatch in that association, the label would not have activated the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be changed to something like this.  the radio button's `name` is what is submitted to the back end, and the `id` is used for front-end things like label association.

**id's should always be unique.**

```
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" />
        <label for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2"/>
        <label for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

If by toggling, you mean the normal behavior of radio buttons, then that happens whenever all the radio buttons in the group have the same `name`.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Due to the `id` and `name` attribute having the same value in your first example, I believe you may be confusing the two. With the database communication code you put up, it's grabbing the `name="Gender"` and **not** the `id="Gender"`.

Additional information about `id` and `class` though you might find useful as an internet programmer:

The `id` attribute can only apply to one element per HTML document. I would suggest using the `class` attribute instead. The main difference between and `id` and a `class` is that a `class` can be applied to multiple elements.

Here is a working **solution** to the code you provided:

```
<div class="funkyradio">
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" class="radio_grp1"/>
        <label for="radio1">Male</label>
    </div>
    <div class="funkyradio-primary col-md-6">
        <input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio2" class="radio_grp1"/>
        <label for="radio2">Female</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the class `.radio_grp1` as the name so that you know that you're referring to a group of radio buttons rather than just one.

Moreover, if you're using a library like bootstrap, it's very common that an element will already have an assigned `class`. To solve this issue, you can assign a single element *multiple* classes by adding a space in the string following the `class` attribute like so:

```
<input type="radio" name="radio" id="radio2" class="radio radio_grp1"/>
```

Hope this was useful!

Comment: Thank you. Andi got in 1st with the comment above though both very useful / the same answer.

Comment: I believe mine was first, but I think they order equal-upped votes posts in order from highest reputation to lowest reputation. Either that, or it was because I made an edit after @andi posted. Either way, I appreciate your thanks! Have a nice day! I just started this account today so I have to build up rep. :)